# Laravel Url two levels deep

Tags: laravel, url

Learning Laravel, I have set up a dev area on AWS with an Ubuntu server.  I can create pages that are one level deep

```
Route::get('/campgrounds','CampgroundController@index');
```

These work fine but when I go two levels deep they don't work. When I try to create a route that is two levels deep I get a "that page your looking for doesn't exist".

```
Route::get('/campgrounds/create', function (){
    return view('welcome');
});
```

I don't see anything in the logging.log file that is erring out. Is there a Laravel setting I need or setting on Apache that needs changing? Maybe something in the `.env` file?

Here is my routes running

```
# php artisan route:list
```

[image: Routes list]

Here is my Apache site configuration:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/laravel/pubic>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Multiviews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

AccessFileName .htaccess
```

Comment: Thanks Tama but that is not it.  I will edit the post so it looks the same. I have tried with / and without / nothing seems to be working.

Comment: Show your Apache site configuration.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain but is it safe to paste that publicly? Do you need just a section of that or the whole config file?

Comment: you should check this config `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` and setup correct `DocumentRoot`

Comment: DocumentRoot /var/www/html/laravel/public    @Ben This is the DocRoot, should it be directed at something different?

Comment: try running `php artisan route:list` to see if it is actually registered.

Comment: Make sure you have the `mod_rewrite` module enabled.

Comment: @Wreigh I updated the routes in the original post.  The mod_rewrite was an issue I was having earlier.  I was only able to get the root_url to show until I added the mod_rewrite to apache

Comment: run command  php artisan route:clear

Comment: Double check your Route definition order - if you defined your wildcard `/campgrounds/{campground}` route _first_, it's the route being matched when trying to visit `/campgrounds/create` even though you also defined that route explicitly. In Laravel, the first matching Route will be resolved regardless of explicitness.

Comment: @AkenRoberts That was the issue, looks like I need to do more reading about route order and wildcards.  If you want to submit an answer I will mark it as my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Laravel, routes will be checked in the order they are defined. As soon as there's a match, checking will stop and it will load the appropriate Closure/Controller.

If you define a wildcard route before an explicit route with the same pattern, the wildcard will match first.

In this example, the URI `/campgrounds/create` will be matched by the first wildcard route, even though the exact route has been defined after:

```
Route::get('/campgrounds/{campground}', ...);

Route::get('/campgrounds/create', ...);
```

Keep your wildcard routes after your explicit routes, and you should be okay:

```
Route::get('/campgrounds/create', ...);

Route::get('/campgrounds/{campground}', ...);
```